# clientY выдает underfined

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Почему в коде ниже `clientY` равен undefined?

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', e => {
  console.log(document.querySelector('section').clientY);
});
```

```html
<div>qw</div>
<div>qwq</div>
<div>wq</div>
<div>ad</div>
<div>qw</div>
<div>qwq</div>
<div>wq</div>
<div>ad</div>
<div>qw</div>
<div>qwq</div>
<div>wq</div>
<div>ad</div>
<div>qw</div>
<div>qwq</div>
<div>wq</div>
<div>ad</div>
<div>qw</div>
<div>qwq</div>
<div>wq</div>
<div>ad</div>
<div>qw</div>
<div>qwq</div>
<div>wq</div>
<div>ad</div>
<section>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus temporibus eius mollitia cupiditate earum ex eaque ut laudantium magni tempore vel, nulla libero, animi tenetur accusamus consequuntur obcaecati ipsa quibusdam?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit
  amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, facilis fuga at voluptatibus laudantium magni! Id aspernatur quaerat consequatur. Eligendi officiis voluptas, voluptates consequatur accusamus cum distinctio? At, doloribus ipsa!</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что `clientY` это свойство событий интерфейса `MouseEvent`, таких как:  `click, dblclick, mouseup, mousedown`. Со `scroll` вы работаете по-другому:

```js
document.addEventListener('scroll', e => {
  console.log(window.scrollY);
});
```

```html
<div>qw</div>
<div>qwq</div>
<div>wq</div>
<div>ad</div>
<div>qw</div>
<div>qwq</div>
<div>wq</div>
<div>ad</div>
<div>qw</div>
<div>qwq</div>
<div>wq</div>
<div>ad</div>
<div>qw</div>
<div>qwq</div>
<div>wq</div>
<div>ad</div>
<div>qw</div>
<div>qwq</div>
<div>wq</div>
<div>ad</div>
<div>qw</div>
<div>qwq</div>
<div>wq</div>
<div>ad</div>
<section>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus temporibus eius mollitia cupiditate earum ex eaque ut laudantium magni tempore vel, nulla libero, animi tenetur accusamus consequuntur obcaecati ipsa quibusdam?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit
  amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, facilis fuga at voluptatibus laudantium magni! Id aspernatur quaerat consequatur. Eligendi officiis voluptas, voluptates consequatur accusamus cum distinctio? At, doloribus ipsa!</section>
```